# Questions to understand the resources/resource file in c# and what it can be used for

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm having a huge problem understanding, how to manage static-files (like images, icons etc.) the best way in an asp.net core project.

I just read articles and questions about the resource file, when its about the localization.
Can't it be my pure filemanager? Like if I'm hosting a webserver and provide some PDFs that are created on the fly and I need some Icons in that PDF, wouldn't it be clever, to put it in the resource manager that I can use it like "Properties.Resource.Icon" instead of using a path and convert it? And if it's so, can't i use this instead of the wwwroot, when I need those Icons on the webpage too, to prevent that I have those Icons twice in my project?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Its quite difficult to understand what you are asking for here...here is a good article on how to ask a good SO question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Both are valid options but this questions seems to be primarily about opinions and that's difficult to answer because it depends on so many factors that are not clear from your question. If you want to access data from embedded resources, you'll have to write a custom controller/action to read and deliver it. There's afaik not standard middleware available. I personally would stay with static files in wwwroot in most cases.